# Email encryption and passphrase caching using thunderbird, enigmail, linux arch and kde

Tags: thunderbird, arch-linux, kde, gnupg, enigmail

I fiddled a bit around to get this passphrase caching working. So post my way to go here, to be able to look up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packages to install:

- thunderbird-enigmail
- pinentry-qt
- kde-agent

I created the key pair using the enigmail wizard inside Thunderbird.

The pinentry-qt package is used for the passphrase query.

The 'kde-agent' delivers startup and shutdown scripts for the gpg-agent for kde.

Afterwards you can edit

```
~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
```

to edit caching times for you private key passphrase.

After one restart you should be able to enter only once the passphrase per given default-cache-ttl time span.

You can also configure `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` and add the following line:

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-kwallet
```

to enable the GPG Passphrase Management with your KDE wallet

More Infos: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#gpg-agent